# Importing methods from Python class into another class instance

Tags: python, class, inheritance

Let's say I've got python object `A`, that is an instance of class `A`.  Every instance of class `A` has an attribute `SubType`.

I've also got classes `SubType_B`, `SubType_C`, and `SubType_D`, each of which has a method called `ingest()`.  The `ingest()` method was previously using `(self)` to get all the parameters it needed, but that `self` is now the instance of class `A`.

What is the most elegant way to inherit / use the method `ingest()` from a `SubType` class (e.g. `SubType_A`), using the `self` from object `A`?

Previously, the `ingest()` method was defined in class `A`, but I would like to break that out into separate classes.  Class `A` is instantiated, and based on the `SubType` parameter, that object would inherit the correct `ingest()` method from the corresponding `SubType` class.

In real simple terms, I'd like one object to grab a method from another object, as if it were its own.

Comment: [If you have an instance of `A`, then how would a child's method be relevant to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Keep the relationship well defined - make a new controlling class which passes the instance of `A` as necessary to the instance of `SubType` and remove the `SubType` attribute from `A`. That is, the new class will have an instance of `A` and an instance of `SubType` which is deals with as it should.

Comment: @HenryGomersall, a controlling class is a good thought, thank you, will look into that.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, you're right, it's not.  The question was perhaps too loosely defined, stating not my end goal, but how to perform something ill-conceived.  The idea of a controlling class, as suggested in other comments, intuited my intent despite the incoherence.  Thanks for the XY problem link though, good to keep in mind.

Comment: Why not creating a metaclass which will return a class with the proper ingest method based on the subclass type? This metaclass would have direct access to any of your subclasses bases and would be able to take the decisions, in its new method.

Answer (score 0):

*UPDATE*
Final solution was to make a factory function that returns instances of the `SubType` classes.  This factory reads information in parameters passed to it, that determine which `SubType` class to instantiate.  The `SubType` classes all extend `Class A`.

I had envisioned things backwards, thinking I started with the most general class, then incorporated attributes and methods from sub-classes.  This factory-like-function does the requisite information gathering, then instantiates the appropriate sub-class.

Thanks to @HenryGomersall and @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams for ideas and clarification.